# Documentation for .NET REST API with NancyFx

Tags: rest, documentation, nancy

I am developing a REST API based on NancyFx on .NET and I would like to attach a documentation framework like IODocs or Swagger. But as far as I understand, those are not directly compatiblible with .NET and NancyFx. Any suggestions to solves this or alternative documentation frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at [Carte](https://github.com/devo-ps/carte) - it'll use Jekyll to generate a static API docs site, so it's not attached to any particular REST framework. There's also a post from the creators [explaining why they wrote it](http://devo.ps/blog/2013/02/07/why-we-dropped-iodocs-and-swagger.html) (an approach I personally agree with)

Comment: Carte runs on Jekyll, which officially only runs on Linux and Mac, so it's probably not a very good candidate for someone who's writing applications in .NET.

Comment: @Moeri While not officially supported, the Jekyll site has information on running on windows at http://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/